# Get parent product thumbnail filter in WooCommerce Cart and Checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm wondering if there's a way to display the parent product thumbnail for all child products in the cart and checkout pages in WooCommerce. Is there a filter for doing something like this?

Answer (score 2):

All the thumbnails in the cart are run through the `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` [filter](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart.php#L53):

```
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

However, if a variation does not have its own thumbnail, WooCommerce will automatically show its [parent's thumbnail](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php#L345-362):

```
/**
 * Gets the main product image.
 *
 * @param string $size (default: 'shop_thumbnail')
 * @return string
 */
public function get_image( $size = 'shop_thumbnail', $attr = array() ) {
    if ( $this->variation_id && has_post_thumbnail( $this->variation_id ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $this->variation_id, $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail( $this->id ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $this->id, $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( ( $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $this->id ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( $parent_id ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $parent_id, $size , $attr);
    } else {
        $image = wc_placeholder_img( $size );
    }
    return $image;
}
```

If you aren't seeing this, then you possibly have outdated theme templates.

**EDIT**

With further information, you are apparently referring to grouped products. You can always tell if a product is "grouped" as its `post_parent` is set to the product ID of the grouped product. A top-level product as a `post_product` of 0. You can find the `post_parent` information in the data passed to the first filter I mentioned: `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` to come up with the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'so_30736886_cart_item_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
function so_30736886_cart_item_thumbnail( $image, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset( $cart_item['product_id'] ) && isset( $cart_item['data'] ) && $cart_item['data']->post->post_parent > 0 ){
        $_parent = wc_get_product( $cart_item['data']->post->post_parent );
        $image = $_parent->get_image();
    }

    return $image;
}
```

If a product has a `post_parent` then we get the the thumbnail for the parent "Group" product.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually setting featured images for each linked product of a group. But the featured images are solid color .jpg to show to color that corresponds each linked product. But in the cart pages I'd like to show replace the child product thumbnails with their parent featured image. Can't seem to find anyone trying to do this so far.

Comment: The first filter I mentioned is still relevant in your case and maybe add this information to your original question.