# Showing the main product image in the cart thumbnail, instead of the variation image in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store that has products with multiple variations.

In the cart, it shows a thumbnail of the product variation image.  This is not good, because the variation is actually just a text image, so you can't see the actual product the text is going onto.

How can I force Woo Commerce to show only the main product image, not the variation on the cart page?

Thanks!!

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30737874/1004312

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following code in active theme's `functions.php`.

```
function getCartItemThumbnail( $img, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);

        if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // Return variable product thumbnail instead variation.
            return $product->get_image();
        }
    }

    return $img;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'getCartItemThumbnail', 111, 2 );
```

Comment: Bear with me because i'm a novice.  This gets added to cart.php?  This is the section that calls the thumbnail: <td class="product-thumbnail">

      <?php
       $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

       if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
        echo $thumbnail;
       } else {
        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
       }
      ?>

Comment: Or I add to functions.php probably?

Comment: I added to the functions file and it is still returning the variation image.

Comment: @MelissaBanks - You can add the code in a separate or existing plugin files or theme's functions.php. Also, As I mentioned you need to add code to get main product image.

Comment: Ah ok - sorry, like I said a bit novice here and still learning.

Comment: So - I could insert the code pasted above (?php $thumbnail etc) into that line for the function, and that would work?  Like this:   function getCartItemThumbnail(){
<?php $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); if ( ! $product_permalink ) { echo $thumbnail; } else { printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); } ?>

    return $main_prod_thumbnail;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'getCartItemThumbnail');

Comment: @MelissaBanks - Right now I am at office. I'll modify the code once I'll be at home and will let you know. :)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.  This has been a thorn in my side for over a week!

Comment: @MelissaBanks - Hi! Updated the answer. Please go through it and let me know :)

Comment: Wow!  I cannot thank you enough!!!! This worked!!! I have been trying everything for weeks.  Thank you again!!!!